# Getting value to equal the checked radio item

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button, checked

I can't get the checked radio input to equal the value. Instead, it seems like it's using the first listed item. I tried adding the checked value to items that didn't come first, but that didn't work. Is there maybe a way to add "checked" to the getElement?

```js
let curPage = 0;

let pronouns = document.getElementById("pronouns").value;
if (pronouns = "1") {
  pronoun1 = "he";
  pronoun2 = "his";
  pronoun3 = "he's";
} else if (pronouns = "2") {
  pronoun1 = "she";
  pronoun2 = "her";
  pronoun3 = "her's";
} else if (pronouns = "3") {
  pronoun1 = "they";
  pronoun2 = "theirs";
  pronoun3 = "they're";
}
let verb = document.getElementById("skill").value;
let place = document.getElementById("city").value;



function nextPage() {
  let page1 = `<p>In your hometown of ${place} you find that your world has turned upside down.</p> <p>"<span style="text-transform:capitalize;">${pronoun3}</span> over here!`;
  let page2 = `Div replacement content 2`;
  let page3 = `Div replacement content 3`;
  let showInfo = [page1, page2, page3];


  let story = document.getElementById('story');
  story.innerHTML = showInfo[curPage];
  if (curPage < 2) {
    curPage++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="story">
 <form>
  <h2>Start Your Adventure!</h2>
  <h3>Who are you?</h3>

 
  <p>Pronouns: <br>

    <input type="radio" id="pronouns" name="pronouns" value="1" checked="">He/His<br>
    <input type="radio" id="pronouns" name="pronouns" value="2">She/Her<br>
    <input type="radio" id="pronouns" name="pronouns" value="3">They/Them<br></p>
  <p>Hometown:<br>
    <input type="radio" id="city" name="city" value="Portland" checked>Portland<br>
    <input type="radio" id="city" name="city" value="Vancouver">Vancouver<br></p>
  <p>Best Skill:<br>
    <input type="radio" id="skill" name="skill" value="swimming" checked>Swimming<br>
    <input type="radio" id="skill" name="skill" value="running">Running<br>
    <input type="radio" id="skill" name="skill" value="cooking">Cooking<br>
  </p>

</div>
<button onclick="nextPage()">Next</button>
```

Comment: The id must be unique.

Comment: I made you a snippet and added a `}` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to make the following changes

1. Use the name instead of having multiple identical IDs which you are not allowed to have
2. Wrap all in the click/function or the user will not be able to change the values
3. You do not need a form tag

```js
let curPage = 0;

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("getStory").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let pronouns = document.querySelector("[name=pronouns]:checked").value;
    if (pronouns = "1") {
      pronoun1 = "he";
      pronoun2 = "his";
      pronoun3 = "he's";
    } else if (pronouns = "2") {
      pronoun1 = "she";
      pronoun2 = "her";
      pronoun3 = "her's";
    } else if (pronouns = "3") {
      pronoun1 = "they";
      pronoun2 = "theirs";
      pronoun3 = "they're";
    }
    let verb = document.querySelector("[name=skill]:checked").value
    let place = document.querySelector("[name=city]:checked").value;

    let page1 = `<p>In your hometown of ${place} you find that your world has turned upside down.</p> <p>"<span style="text-transform:capitalize;">${pronoun3}</span> over here!`;
    let page2 = `Div replacement content 2`;
    let page3 = `Div replacement content 3`;
    let showInfo = [page1, page2, page3];

    let story = document.getElementById('story');
    story.innerHTML = showInfo[curPage];
    if (curPage < 2) {
      curPage++;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="story">
  <h2>Start Your Adventure!</h2>
  <h3>Who are you?</h3>

  <p>Pronouns: <br>

    <input type="radio" name="pronouns" value="1" checked="">He/His<br>
    <input type="radio" name="pronouns" value="2">She/Her<br>
    <input type="radio" name="pronouns" value="3">They/Them<br></p>
  <p>Hometown:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="city" value="Portland" checked>Portland<br>
    <input type="radio" name="city" value="Vancouver">Vancouver<br></p>
  <p>Best Skill:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="swimming" checked>Swimming<br>
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="running">Running<br>
    <input type="radio" name="skill" value="cooking">Cooking<br>
  </p>
</div>

<button type="button" id="getStory">Next page</button>
```